# page scaling on Zend Pdf generator

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I am trying to make a PDF in PHP which will be used to print onto address labels. I have made measurements carefully so that the text lines up with the labels. However, when going to print them, page scaling messes up all those measurements, and now nothing will line up. I have to manually turn off page scaling, but my customer's are not willing to put up with this extra step. What can i do?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but I had a similar problem and I ended doing it in HTML an setting sizes in millimetres.